# How to ignore 'null' in order by clause

Tags: linq

How i can ignore Null in name property when orderby

```
student.Students= student.student.OrderBy(s=> s.Name ?? null).ToList();
```

The above code always return `list of students having Name = null as 1st element` in the list and `student with name 'system' in the end.`

What i want to `ignore/exclude null in orderby`. the n`ull should always come to end of the the list`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a conditional `OrderBy`:

```
student.Students= student.student
    .OrderBy(s=> s.Name == null ? 1 : 0)
    .ThenBy(s => s.Name)
    .ToList();
```

This splits first into two groups, the items with `s.Name != null` and those with `s.Name == null`. The second sort-condition is the `Name` itself.

Comment: Clean, simple, fluent... +1

Comment: @Tim Schmelter thanks you, what does 1: 0 means in your 3rd line of code?

Comment: @simbada: it's just the sort value, if the name is null `1` is taken, if it's not null `0` is taken. Since 0 is less than 1 all non-null come first. You could also write: `.OrderBy(s=> s.Name == null)`. That would work because the result is a `bool` where `true` is "greater" than `false`.